# Ant regex replace without leaving blank lines

Tags: regex, ant, replace

I'm using this regular expression to replace lines that contain `-foo`:

```
^.*?(-foo\b).*$
```

After the replacement, there's a bunch of blank lines left where the lines originally existed. How can I change this to remove the line itself instead of leaving a blank line?

The context that I'm doing this in is an Ant script and here's the full line if it helps:

```
<replaceregexp file=" ... " match="^.*?(-foo\b).*$" replace="" byline="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the line by line processing and change the regular expression to include line separators, replacing every occurrence with a new line.

```
<replaceregexp file=" ... " match="(\r?\n).*?(-foo\b).*\r?\n" replace="\1" flags="g" />
```